# Uploading files into SVN repositories in the VisualSVN Server web interface

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Why isn't it possible? It would be a great feature.

https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#

Comment: File upload in the web interface of VisualSVN Server is available beginning with version 5.1. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

### Update September 2022

Beginning with [version 5.1](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/5.1/), VisualSVN Server supports uploading files in the web interface. See the article [KB206: Uploading files in VisualSVN Server Web Interface](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00206/) for more information.

[image]

---

### Outdated answer

You could use your Subversion client such as TortoiseSVN or svn.exe to upload and modify data stored on VisualSVN Server. Current versions of VisualSVN Server do not support write operations in the repository web interface.

Comment: Uploading file via web interface would be fantastic.